# POST media/ image for twitter with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Can I have an API with AngularJS with which I can upload a image to twitter. When I am using URL like

```
socialshareConfProvider.configure([{
  'provider': 'twitter',
  'conf': {
    'url': 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/120th-anniversary-of-first-modern-olympic-games-6314245085986816.2-5640471028170752-ror.jpg',
    'text': '720kb is enough',
    'via': 'npm',
    'hashtags': 'angularjs,socialshare,angular-socialshare',
    'trigger': 'click',
    'popupHeight': 800,
    'popupWidth' : 400
  }
}]);
```

Its showing direct URL of the image on twitter. Any help for `POST media/upload` of twitter will be great.

Thanks in advance.